# Pressure at the bottom of the fluid (fluid mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

There is a question given my book which is stated below

> The three vessels shown in figure have the the same base area. Equal volumes of a liquid are poured in the three vessels the force on the base will be
>   [image]
>
> $1.$ Maximum in vessel $a$
>
> $2.$ Maximum in vessel $b$
>
> $3.$ Maximum in vessel $c$
>
> $4.$ Equal in all the vessels

Given answer: $c$

As the question mentions equal volume of fluid and base area of vessels are same so the fluid must rise to same height in all three and hence pressure at the bottom should be same for all ($p = h\rho g$) and so $d$ should be right option. Please explain why $c$ is the right option and correct me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance for help !!!

Comment: I guess that it will be the one where the same amount of liquid will spread the highest, but how do you expect us to do your homework if you don't even show us the figure?

Comment: @Matt where not supposed to do the OPs homework regardless. Check out the policy

Comment: Sorry actual i was in mid of uploading and editing.Now i have posted it completely.Have a look

Comment: @BobD I know. Nevertheless, I have noticed that some users, even seasoned ones, do it anyway. But it was not my intention.

Comment: @Nick My initial comment should make it obvious, then.

Comment: @Matt Agree, I have even done so myself. It's hard to resist the urge to help, policy not withstanding.

Comment: @BobD Agreed! :)

Comment: Equal volume of fluid and equal base area do not combine to imply equal height of the liquids. Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pour a liquid into vessel A, the surface of liquid is rising very slowly, so you need much liquid to rise it about e. g. $5$ cm.

For vessel B you don't need so much liquid for the same height, and for vessel C you need minimum.

So pouring the same volume of liquid into each of these vessels you reach the highest column of liquid — and, consequently, the highest pressure to the base — in vessel C.

As the bases have the same area, the force (= pressure $\times$ area) will be highest in vessel C, too.

Answer (score 0):

The height to which fluid rises depends on the volume of container, not only on the base area. It is evident that c will have least volume for a given height. So for same volume of fluid, water will rise to maximum height in c.