# Pressure variation in liquids with varying densities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

There is a question mentioned in my textbook which is given below

> Equal masses of three liquids are kept in 3 identical cylindrical vessels A, Band C . The densities are Da,Db and Dc with Da < Db < Dc.The force on the base will be

1. maximum in vessel A
2. maximum in vessel B
3. maximum in vessel C
4. equal in all vessels

Given answer is option 4

I know that p=hDg   (D is density of fluid)
and from this equation pressure should increase as density increases so correct option should be 3.

Where i am wrong .Please correct me and thanks in advance for your great help!!!

Comment: Nick, could you please type the full question? Your second sentence ended abruptly.

Comment: See this and its answer : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488644/207455

Comment: i was just editting it .sorry for inconvenience and it's complete now.

Comment: the question of the shared link was asked by me and as far i see both are different questions.

Comment: From that equation pressure _shouldn't_ increase.  You just haven't considered everything in that equation.

Comment: So, you show 4 options numbered, but say option D? did you mean option 4?  Need to improve your editing...

Comment: @SolarMike sorry for that .I corrected them.

Comment: @JMac what I am missing out . please explain

Comment: It asks for the force, not the pressure.  What is the total weight of each liquid and how do they compare to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question states that "equal" masses are in each container.

It also states that the densities are different.

What is does **not** say is that the volume is the same in each container.

So, I would put option 4 as correct.

As an example, put 800g of water in a container, and then 800g of cooking oil in an identical container. Do they have the same height or different...